# Recursively add to strings in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm tackling a recursion problem that returns a string of "hi"'s where the first "hi" has a capital H and the string ends with an exclamation point. I have the code below so far but I'm not sure how to prevent subsequent occurrences of "hi" having a capital H. Any guidance would be welcome.

```js
function greeting(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return "";
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return "Hi!"
  } else {
    return `${'Hi' + greeting(n - 1)}`
  }
}
console.log(greeting(3)) // should return Hihihi!
console.log(greeting(5)) // should return Hihihihihi!
```

Comment: I need it to return Hihihi! My current code capitalises all the H's

Comment: Just a `.toLowerCase()` is missing in your code. `${'Hi' + greeting(n - 1).toLowerCase()}`. You don't need the `n === 1` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around your problem is to pass a flag to the function which indicates whether this is the first call, and only in that case capitalise the `hi`. Note that you can simplify the code slightly by returning a `!` when `n == 0`; then you don't need to special case `n == 1`:

```js
function greeting (n, first = true) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return "!";
  } 
  else {
    return `${(first ? 'Hi' : 'hi') + greeting(n - 1, false)}`
  } 
}
console.log(greeting(3)) // should return Hihihi!
console.log(greeting(5)) // should return Hihihihihi!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a `.toLowerCase()` is missing in your code.

```
`${'Hi' + greeting(n - 1).toLowerCase()}`
```

You don't need the `n === 1` step.

```js
function greeting(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return "!";
  } else {
    return `${'Hi' + greeting(n - 1).toLowerCase()}`
    //------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
console.log(greeting(3)) // should return Hihihi!
console.log(greeting(5)) // should return Hihihihihi!
```